# "I had a choice between something AND/OR something else"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I have been scratching my head over this, as both sound like they could be correct, I just can't figure out which one is more so:

> I had a choice between apples and oranges.

Or

> I had a choice between apples or oranges.

I feel like the first is probably correct, but is the second wrong, or just not preferred?

Answer (score 0):

Using "or" is like you are mixing two sentences in a single one.
You have the choice between these two phrases :
" Do you prefer appels or oranges ?"
" Choose between apples and oranges."